# Webcam not working in Ubuntu in vmware virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, logitech-webcam

I want to use a Logitech Webcam C210 in Ubuntu, using the virtualising system of VMware Player 6.0.5 in Windows 7 but the problem is that although I have the webcam connected and Ubuntu identifies it, when I open an application like Cheese or any other of this type, the screen is all black and i can't take a picture nor a video. This also happens to me with the integred webcam of the computer, so the problem is not with the webcam.

The camera led turns on when I open the application for taking pictures or videos.

Thanks for reading and for the help.

Comment: There's likely an issue with the driver on the VM and/or it isn't being shared properly between the host machine and the VM.

Comment: Okay, I found this link https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/242 the problem they are having there i the same I am having in VMware, where it is not supposed to happen. I don't know if you have a solution on that, but please make me know if you do! Thanks.